# Pass data in JWT token that is readable by angular

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, angular, openid

My angular (angular4) application uses JWT, and i am using the angualr2-jwt project on the client side.  On the server side i am using .NET core and would like to add extra data in the token (full name, email) but i would like to be able to read that on my angular application.

Is this possible and if so, how?

On the .net core side, i am using the openidcore project available from github, i can use the `.AddProperty` method of an `AuthenticationToken` to add my data, but i am not sure how to get this via angular?

Answer (score 0):

jwt is is plain data with base64 encoding, you can anytime decode it with base 64 decoding.

Comment: Thought JWT was split into 3 or something?  You have a simple example?

Comment: can you provide one jwt token? I will help you get data out of it, using plain JS.